# PHP errors out after form submission. Why?

Tags: php

I creating a little settings page for my website but when debugging I found that when you submit the form, it removes all of the input fields. What it should do is successfully change the rows in the SQL, however, does not.

I've tried `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `MODIFY` but all do not work. I am unaware if `UPDATE` requires another function I need to call. Any help is appreciated.

My PHP:

```php
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        $displayname = $_POST['displayname'];
                        $bio = $_POST['bio'];
                        $uid = $_SESSION['username'];

                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET displayname = '$displayname' SET bio = '$bio' WHERE username = $uid");
                        $stmt->execute();                     
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple `SET` clauses in an `UPDATE` query. It's `SET col1 = val1, col2 = val2, ...`

Comment: You should use bound parameters instead of substituting variables into the SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by "removes all of the input fields"? The query should fail due to the syntax error, it won't remove anything.

Comment: Well, it removes all the content inside the `fieldset`. And when the query fails it does so. @Barmar

Comment: When you submit a form, the page reloads with whatever the script outputs. Your script doesn't produce any output, so you get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

capture any error when doing the SQL

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //bind the data properly
    $data = [
        'displayname' => trim($_POST['displayname']);
        'bio' => trim($_POST['bio']);
        'uid' => $_SESSION['username'];
        ];

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET displayname = :displayname, bio = :bio WHERE username = :uid");
        $stmt->execute($data);
        //echo success message here
    }
    catch (PDOException $error)
    {
        return $error->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

and set/bind your data properly.